# Typescript type fields combinations

Tags: typescript

Look at this type:

```
type MyType =
  | { a: number }
  | { b: number }
  | { c: number }
  | ({ b: number } & { c: number });
```

I want to forbid combination of a with b or c.

```
  const o1: MyType = { a: 10 };             // only a: OK
  const o2: MyType = { b: 10 };             // only b: OK
  const o3: MyType = { c: 10 };             // only c: OK
  const o4: MyType = { b: 10, c: 10 };     // combine b and c: OK

  // const o5: MyType = {};                     // Forbidden (no fields)
  const o6: MyType = { a: 10, b: 10 };        // Forbidden (I should not be able to combine a and b)
```

I don't understand because typescript allows me to instantiate o6. It should not because I don't want to see a and b together...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look pretty, but XOR will help you in this case.

```
type MyType =
  | { a: number, b?: never }
  | { b: number, a?: never }
  | { c: number }
  | ({ b: number } & { c: number });
```

Easier to understand is to consider Union as union from any type. Its not OR basically.